# What is the effect of echoing a path in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I have a bash script with the following if statement:

```
if [ "$(PATH)/$(FILE)" != "`echo $(PATH)/$(FILE)`" ]; then [code omitted] fi
```

What could be the purpose of comparing a file path with the same file path echoed back?

The bash script is embedded within a rule in a Makefile.  Thus, the notation for the variables is different than for a normal bash script.  $(PATH), for instance, will be replaced by the PATH variable, which is defined within the Makefile.

Comment: Maybe I'm showing my ignorance, but it seems like `PATH` and `FILE` are being treated as commands.  And I've never heard of the either one.  So what do they do?

Comment: Also, maybe my eyesight is going, but it looks like the `echo` command is never actually executed, seeing as it's in single quotes and not backticks.

Comment: Like @TimPote says, `PATH` and `FILE` are not being treated as variables. If they were they would not have the parentheses between the $ and the name. There is a `file` command, it gives information about the filetype of a file, not sure what's happening here though without more code

Comment: Oops... I'll clarify above...

Comment: @TimPote: Yes, the single quotes are backticks, and the notation for the variables is due to this being embedded within a Makefile, as I just updated above...  I apologize for the inaccuracies...

Comment: depending on what you see in the 'then' clause (omitted), this seems to be a test to see that `echo` works as expected. :-? Would this be  a make file from a package that uses autoconf/configure? Good luck!

Comment: @shellter: It's not testing echo...

Comment: testing, in that the Lefthand side is something that can't change, where as the Righthand side IS something the MIGHT change, based out what OS's echo is being called.  Oh, you mean the 'then' clause doesn't do any thing that would have been related to changes from `echo`, Ok. I also give credit @chepner 's explanation. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: I see what you mean...  test to see if echo behaves as expected due to implementation differences...  That's not the case in this case, but thanks for your thoughts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the author of the Makefile expects `PATH` and/or `FILE` to contain variable references, something like

```
PATH='/$foo/bar'
```

so that `$PATH` is not necessarily the same as the expansion of `$(echo $PATH)`.